# How to sample a multinomial distribution using sample() in R?

Tags: r, sample, multinomial

I was wondering how to sample a multinomial distribution with sample() instead of rmultinom().

> X=X1,X2,X3
> size=10
> probability=0.3,0.4,0.3

And I want to know the probability that P(X1=3,X2=4,X3=3).

How can I achieve this in R? Thank you very much!

I failed to achieve this using sample().

Comment: `sample` gives a discrete uniform, in a multinomial distribution each `Xi` follows a binomial distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do it:

```r
(
sample(1:3,replace=TRUE,size=10, prob = c(0.3,0.4,0.3)) 
  |> factor(levels = 1:3)
  |> table()
)
```

You can then use `replicate()` to do an experiment.

```
res <- replicate(10000,
  sample(1:3,replace=TRUE,size=10, prob = c(0.3,0.4,0.3)) 
     |> factor(levels = 1:3)
     |> table()
     |> paste(collapse = "")
   )
mean(res == "343") ## 0.0794
```

Check against `dmultinom`:

```r
dmultinom(c(3,4,3), size = 10, prob = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.3))
## 0.078382
```